# Singularity of a sum of Bessel functions

Tags: limits, summation, bessel-functions, singularity

I would like to know the nature of $$\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}J_{0}(mx)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k}m^{2k}x^{2k}}{2^{2k}(k!)^{2}}$$ as $x\to0^{+}$. For any $x>0$, this series of Bessel functions converges (being a sequence of numbers decaying in magnitude and varying in phase). However, at $x=0$, the series does not converge and I would like to know at what rate it diverges e.g. as $ln(x)$ or $x^{-1}$. Clearly you can't swap any of the limits involved so I'm a bit stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: See the last evaluated example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schl%C3%B6milch%27s_Series).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Euler-Maclaurin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula):
$$
\sum_{m>0}J_0(mx)=\int_{m>0}J_0(mx)+\mathcal O(1)=\frac{1}{x}+\mathcal O(1)
$$